# php postgresql persistent connections always close

Tags: php, apache, postgresql, pdo

I have an Apache/PHP app on one server and a PostgreSQL database on a second server. They are configured to connect via SSL. Everything works, except that even though `$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT, true);` is in the script the TCP connections are always closed. PHP.INI has `pgsql.allow_persistent = On` `pgsql.auto_reset_persistent = Off` `pgsql.max_persistent = 30` and `pgsql.max_links = 30`. Using `sudo netstat -nap` I can see that there are no ESTABLISHED connections between the two servers. What else do I need to do to keep the connections open? New connection overhead is 10-12 ms per request.

Comment: Use a connection pool like pgBouncer. Always.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this note a fair way down one of the php manual pages:

> If you wish to use persistent connections, you must set
>   PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT in the array of driver options passed to the PDO
>   constructor. If setting this attribute with PDO::setAttribute() after
>   instantiation of the object, the driver will not use persistent
>   connections.

That's where I went wrong. I was using this:

```
$host = explode('.',$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);
$db = new PDO($host[0]);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT, true);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

When I should have been doing this:

```
$host = explode('.', $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);
$db = new PDO($host[0],null,null,array(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT=>true,
      PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE=>PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
      PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE=>PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
```

The DSN's are in a pdo.ini file. The null user and password are fortunately ignored or else this wouldn't work either. Now `new PDO` takes 0.02 ms instead of 10 ms.